# Drupal 8 - How to Programatically Resize Image?

Tags: drupal, image-resizing, drupal-8

I'm developing a module. The image saves on the server correctly, and I could manually write PHP code to resize the image... but what is the native way to resize the image programatically in Drupal 8?

I can see an Image class, but it needs to work with an image toolkit... this is the bit I'm stuck on.

Thanks =)

Comment: post what you have so far

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the answer is to use drupals image styles system which is part of drupal core.

If anyone stumbles across the Image class, this is not the native quick-fire way... Its just what drupal uses via image styles.

Answer (score 0):

Here ist the Drupal 8 way to get image style via file uri:

```
use Drupal\file\Entity\File;
use Drupal\image\Entity\ImageStyle;

$fid = 123;
$file = File::load($fid);
$image_uri = ImageStyle::load('your_style-name')->buildUrl($file->getFileUri());
```